# How to use the "Find" function which satisfy two criteria

Tags: excel, vba, function, find, range

The first column contains names that have distinct IDs attached. E.g the first name "Steve" has the ID "1". The other "Steve" the ID "2". I am using the "find" function in order to find the name "Steve" in range A:A but I am struggling to get the "find" function to find the "name" and the corresponding ID "1" in order to differentiate it from the other "Steve" with the ID "2". In other word, the variable "Found" are supposed to contain two informations, the name "Steve" with the ID "1".
I just dont know how to incorporate these two criteria into the "find" function.

[image]

```
Set RIC=worksheet(„Tabel“).range(„A“&t)
Set ID= worksheet(„Tabel“).range(„C“&t)

Set Found= worksheet(„rules“).range(A:C).Find(RIC,ID)
```

Comment: That's not how find works I'm afraid. If you do want to continue that path, you'll need to use FindNext and check it's offset untill you found your second criteria. How about an AutoFilter? Or an Evaluate operation? What's you end goal? Pull info from any other column?

Comment: You can always use a helper column concatenating the two and then search on that.

Comment: The aim is e.g. that in sheet 2 for "Steve" with the ID "1" will be some calculations conducted. The next step is to get back to the first sheet again, looking for "Steve" with the ID "1" and to put the calculated result from sheet 2 in column "B" on the same row as "Steve" with the ID "1". In other words, I am trying to use the ID to differentiate the names which appear more than once to that the calcuated results get allocated to the right name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `FIND` in the first place, that's what array formulas are for.

[image]

```
.FormulaArray =  "=INDEX(C1:C5,MATCH(1,((A1:A5=""Steve"")*(B1:B5=""C"")),0))"
```

Comment: Can I use the Index as a VBA code, e.g. the INDEX contains the two values namely "name" and "ID"?

Comment: @YavuzTopal Just try it and see for yourself